# Is it safe to transfer private data through Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am using **[Google Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks)** to create task and **Firebase functions** to handle it.
I can pass **payload** to my handler using **[body](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#HttpRequest)** parameter 
But i am not sure is it secure to pass **private** data using payload without encoding or better use some cipher?

Also I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#target_routing)

> In App Engine tasks, both the queue and the task handler run within the same Cloud project. Traffic is encrypted during transport and never leaves Google datacenters

but I'm not sure if it applies to this case

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All depends what you put behind the word "secure".

- Is your data encrypted at rest? Yes, even in Cloud Task (before triggering the task)
- Is your data encrypted in transit? Yes, even when Cloud Task trigger your endpoint.
- Can someone see the data of a task? Yes, if he has enough right, the user can [perform a GET on the task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/get) and view its body data.

So, yes it's secure if you set the correct permission to the users. you can cipher the data, with Cloud KMS for example, if the Cloud Task data are private and you don't want that an Ops, that manage Cloud Task, accesses to the private data; but in this case, don't grant the user the permission on CLoud KMS.